# How can host name be included in MVC2 route mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've got 3 domain names all pointed at the same MVC2 application. What I've got now is the homecontroller acting as a traffic cop and redirecting to controllers and views for the specific host name. But I don't like the URI result this causes...

ex: 
www.webhost1.com/webhost1/imagegallery
www.webhost2.com/webhost2/imagegallery

I'd prefer to have:

www.webhost1.com/imagegallery

Is there a way to define the routes in global.asax that would include the host name in the routing evaluation so that the URI looks less redundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha!, it took a bit of fiddling (and a peak in and old book) but I think I've solved it.

You need to create a custom route constraint.
This is the one I made quickly:

```
 public class hostnameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        protected string _hostname;

        public hostnameConstraint (string hostname)
        {
            _hostname = hostname;
        }

        bool IRouteConstraint.Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Url.Host == _hostname)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then you simply add it to your routes and specify which hostname you want the route to apply to. like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ImageGallery", "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
            new { hostname = new hostnameConstraint("webhost1.com") }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "ImageGallery", "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
            new { hostname = new hostnameConstraint("webhost2.com") }
        );
```

and so on and so forth. I don't know how your routes are layed out, but the point is that now you can have seperate routes for the hostnames. Which should enable you to do what you're after.

Comment: You sir are my hero! I just tested this and it's working perfectly.

Comment: This is awesome.  Exactly what I was lookin for.  I am creating a site that we can host domain redirects.  I wanted the site to manage the domains as well as be the redirect.  Adding a route with this constraint allowed me to have the normal site under the host domain and any other domains would be redirected accordingly.  Thanks!