# MVC3 areas, routing and urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Having absorbed myself in MVC over the last 9 months or so, the one area I seem to be struggling with are Areas and Routing.

A couple of questions if anyone may help:

1.) Can an MVC3 application and it's associated areas have different Urls?

Example:

- Main app (root) = www.mymvcapp.com
- Mobile app (area) = m.mymvcapp.com
- Admin app (area) = admin.mymvcapp.com
- CustomerService (area) = custsvc.mymvcapp.com

etc, etc, etc...

Any tips or solutions greatly appreciated in advance. It just seems that a lot of the books out there on MVC trend to just glaze over Areas and Routing in general.

Again, this is pretty specific to "AREAS" and routing.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 26 JAN 2012:**

First thing was to get the actual area to work. I've never had any luck with this until I dove in late yesterday.

I created a test MVC project (MvsAreas) with a "Home" controller and a single "Index" action method and view, so good so far.  :)

Added an area called "Admin", added a controller called "HomeController" and added a single "Index" action method and view.

Because I have two home controllers, you will get a run time error. Resolution: use namespaces and then use the overloaded MapRoute method to pass in the namespace.

Root application controller:

```
Namespace MvcAreas.Web.Mvc.Controllers

    Public Class HomeController
        Inherits Controller

        Function Index() As ActionResult

            Return View()

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Admin area controller:

```
Namespace MvcAreas.Areas.Admin.Controllers

    Public Class HomeController
        Inherits Controller

        Function Index() As ActionResult

            Return View()

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Global.asax**

```
Namespace MvcAreas.Web.Mvc

    Public Class MvcApplication
        Inherits HttpApplication

        Shared Sub RegisterGlobalFilters(ByVal filters As GlobalFilterCollection)

            filters.Add(New HandleErrorAttribute())

        End Sub

        Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Root_Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional},
                New String() {"MvcAreas.Web.Mvc.Controllers"}
            )

        End Sub

        Sub Application_Start()

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**AdminAreaRegistration.vb**

```
Namespace MvcAreas.Areas.Admin

    Public Class AdminAreaRegistration
        Inherits AreaRegistration

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property AreaName() As String
            Get
                Return "Admin"
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext)

            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional},
                New String() {"MvcAreas.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}
            )

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

That will get the area and the root working.

Next step; attempt to use some of the reference link below to set up Urls.

If anyone has any suggestions, please feel free to add.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can host name be included in MVC2 route mapping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216098/how-can-host-name-be-included-in-mvc2-route-mapping)

Comment: Not the same question, but close. Leave the question as someone may have a direct answer.

Comment: @Lucero, thanks for the link, I was actually able to use it and resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad I was able to help with the link. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lucero's link (thank you BTW Lucero, this pointed me in the right direction), I was able to get this to work.

Adding to the above project, I added a new class called "HostnameConstraint".

**HomenameConstraint.vb**

```
Namespace MvcAreas.Web.Mvc.Constraints

    Public Class HostnameConstraint
        Implements IRouteConstraint

        Protected Property Hostname As String

        Public Sub New(hostName As String)

            Me.Hostname = hostName

        End Sub

        Private Function Match(httpContext As HttpContextBase, route As Route, parameterName As String, values As RouteValueDictionary,
                               routeDirection As RouteDirection) As Boolean Implements IRouteConstraint.Match

            If httpContext.Request.Url.Host = Me.Hostname Then
                Return True
            End If

            Return False

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Before I go on, you do have to set up IIS for whatever hostnames you want to be associated with the site (I know this is pretty obvious, but someone will ask).  :)

**Now change Global.asax**

```
        Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Test2",
                "{controller}/{action}",
                New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"},
                New With {.hostname = New MvcAreas.Web.Mvc.Constraints.HostnameConstraint("www.mvcareas.com")},
                New String() {"MvcAreas.Web.Mvc.Controllers"}
                )

        End Sub
```

**Now change AdminAreaRegistration.vb**

```
Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As AreaRegistrationContext)

    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"},
        New With {.hostname = New MvcAreas.Web.Mvc.Constraints.HostnameConstraint("admin.mvcareas.com")},
        New String() {"MvcAreas.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}
        )


End Sub
```

Now when I run the application, www.mvcareas.com brings me to the correct Index action from the root home controller.

When I enter in admin.mvcareas.com, I am brought to the correct index action from the admin area home controller.

All is well and I am a happy camper.  :)

BTW, I know this is a very simplistic application of areas, urls, and routing concepts. But hopefully this post helps someone out that is trying to understand it better or like me, see how we can meet some specific url requirements for a project.

Lucero, thanks again for the link.

Comment: Interestingly, trying to generate links between Areas using the ActionLink or RouteLink Html helpers does not work, the search continues.  :)