# mvc3 areas have hostname

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am looking to create a MVC3 website.  We need at least two areas but we need different url's for each of the areas. Like this:

> domain.com/ goes to /
>
> admin.domain.com/ goes to /areas/admin
>
> anotherSite.com/ goes to /areas/portal

After doing some research I have found [Lucero's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009132/mvc3-areas-routing-and-urls) that you can use HostNameContraint as follows:

```
public class HostNameContraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    protected string _hostname;

    public HostNameContraint(string hostname)
    {
        _hostname = hostname;
    }

    bool IRouteConstraint.Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Url.Host == _hostname)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then register the constraints like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new { hostname = new HostNameContraint("domain.com") },
            new[] { "MVCProject.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin_Default2", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new { hostname = new HostNameContraint("admin.domain.com") },
            new[] { "MVCProject.Controllers.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Portal_Default2", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { area = "Portal", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new { hostname = new HostNameContraint("anotherSite.com") },
            new[] { "MVCProject.Controllers.Areas.Portal.Controllers" }
        );
```

I have IIS setup so that they point to the root folder of the application for each of the sites.  Pointing to the root "Domain.com" works fine but going to either "Admin.domain.com" or "Domain.com/admin/" comes up with a 404 "Resource cannot be found."

**Update**
I have tried it both with the Area name at the beginning of the url and without.

> "Portal/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

The issue is that when the "Portal" area is in the route, the signature does not match the name as "anotherSite.com" and therefore it comes back and says 403.14 - Forbidden.  Cannot list contents of this directory.  It is also important to note that the constructor for HostNameConstraint is never called when the "Portal" area is url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to indicate distinguish the URL as going to an area, the area name needs to be part of the URL.  Otherwise, the area will not be parseable from the URL and you will fall back to the default routing.  Also, it is a good idea to put your default route last - to ensure all other route mappings are tested

Note the addition of "Admin/" and "Portal/" in the corresponding MapRoute call:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Admin_Default2", // Route name
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new { hostname = new HostNameContraint("admin.domain.com") },
        new[] { "MVCProject.Controllers.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Portal_Default2", // Route name
        "Portal/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { area = "Portal", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new { hostname = new HostNameContraint("anotherSite.com") },
        new[] { "MVCProject.Controllers.Areas.Portal.Controllers" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new { hostname = new HostNameContraint("domain.com") },
        new[] { "MVCProject.Controllers" }
    );
```

Comment: yes I have tried it both with the Area name at the beginning and without. IE '"Portal/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters' The issue is that when the "Portal" area is in the route it does not match the name as "anotherSite.com" should point directly to the "Portal" area and therefore "anotherSite.com" does not match against '"Portal/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters'